# Add Azure Key Vault to Dockerized ASP.NET Core 6 web app

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, containers, azure-keyvault

I am trying to add an azure key vault startup dependency to my containerized .net6 web app. I can run the project locally (presumably because my application is leveraging my Visual Studio credentials), but when I run the container locally, the app fails to authenticate (and it looks like the `Az.Account` module is not installed in the container, but I can't find out how to add this). The application is properly registered and I have the proper `AzureClientSecret`.

My `Program.cs` method looks like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, config) =>
            {
                var root = config.Build();
                var vaultName = root["KeyVault:Vault"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vaultName))
                {
                    var secretClient = new SecretClient(
                        new Uri(vaultName),
                        new DefaultAzureCredential());

                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
                }
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

ARG PAT
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER=0
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../nuget/v3/index.json\", \"password\":\"${PAT}\"}]}"

ARG AspNetCoreEnvironment
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ${AspNetCoreEnvironment}

ARG AzureTenantId
ENV AZURE_TENANT_ID ${AzureTenantId}
ARG AzureClientId
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_ID ${AzureClientId}
ARG AzureClientSecret
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET ${AzureClientSecret}

COPY . .
COPY ["Service/Service.csproj", "Service/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Service/Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Service"
RUN dotnet build "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.dll"]
```

To kick off my build, I run: `docker build . -t tag_name --build-args (the ones in the dockerfile)`.

To start the container, I run `docker run tag_name`

The error I get is the following:

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: The ChainedTokenCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
- DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.
- Operating system Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020 isn't supported.
- Azure CLI not installed
- Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
```

This feels like this should be a well solved problem, but I have been having a very hard time. Does anyone have any experience here or have any advice on how to update my docker container definition?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely because the environment variables are set in the `build` image, not in the `base`/`final` image.

That being said, you shouldn't really set secrets as environment variables in your `dockerfile`, unless the build stage requires them and even then ensure they are not being set in the final image. Since they are part of the image, anyone could simply acquire the credentials from it.

You should always set the environment variables when running the container instead.